# Creating expensive components using *ngFor

Tags: angular

I am using Angular4 and am facing following challenge:

**Scenario:**

I have an array of objects which changes as new items are added in the array at second location.

I use *ngFor to loop through and create components bases on this array which can have max dozen objects.

Each of these components are heavy/expensive components containing a few server calls and data binding on 3 grids in each components.

*I need to be adding one at location # 2 or remove any one based on user actions.*

This is a scientific application using statistical data. So, the requirement is a must-have.

**Problem**

The problem is that as the number of objects in the array increase, the new component display become slower and slower since all components are recreated.

Is it possible to I dynamically insert the new component, instead of recreating all of them at each change because that is degrading performance?

Is there a way that I can tell ngFor to not recreate items id they exists?

Please point me if this is being discussed on another thread as I was not able to locate it.
Greatly appreciate any help!

Regards.

Comment: 1-follow **lazy load** keyword , 2-some elements are heavier than other. if you leave a demo here i can help you more

Comment: Try to load components dynamically - https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Hi Taras, I too am thinking about the same. But the problem is there are dozen instances of this component and I need to be adding one at location # 2 or remove any one based on user actions. I am wondering how I can achieve this! (i will add this in the scenario in my question).